# What is the line for reading a file from inside a python package

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I have packaged a python file with with setuptools, unfortunately I encounter FileNotFound when I import the project in other directory. What is the correct way of importing a text file inside a script?

project structure:

```
main_folder/
├─ MANIFEST.in
├─ setup.py
├─ mypgk/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ main.py
│  ├─ files/
│  │  ├─ somewhat.csv
```

here is my setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='mypkg',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=('test*', 'testing*'))
)
```

MANIFEST.in

```
recursive-include mypkg *.csv
```

main.py:

```
import csv 

config_file = os.path.join('mypkg', 'files', 'somewhat.csv') 
with open(config_file, 'r') as config_file:
    reader = csv.reader(config_file)
```

running this script in the same directory works, but when I use it on other directories, FileNotFound error is prompted, Have I missed something?

oddly when I type `python setup.py sdist` it is confirmed in the distribution

```
copying MANIFEST.in -> mypkg-0.0.1
copying setup.py -> mypkg-0.0.1
copying mypkg\main.py -> mypkg-0.0.1\mypkg
copying mypkg\__init__.py -> mypkg-0.0.1\mypkg
copying mypkg.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> mypkg-0.0.1\mypkg.egg-info
copying mypkg.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> mypkg-0.0.1\mypkg.egg-info
copying mypkg.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> mypkg-0.0.1\mypkg.egg-info
copying mypkg.egg-info\top_level.txt -> mypkg-0.0.1\mypkg.egg-info
copying mypkg\files\somewhat.csv -> mypkg-0.0.1\mypkg\files
```

but going in the directory, I found no files folder

Comment: `os.dirname(__file__) + '/files/somewhat.csv`

Comment: module 'os' has no attribute 'dirname' ? Tried os.path.dirname and its No such file or directory

Comment: Try `os.path.dirname(__file__)`

Comment: yes I did, but same error no such file or directory

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+read+file+inside+package

Answer (score 0):

To put @Tim Roberts answer in to your example:

```
import csv 

config_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'files', 'somewhat.csv') 
with open(config_file, 'r') as config_file: 
    reader = csv.reader(config_file)
```

This should work as long as the files directory stays in the same directory as main.py. The name of the directory that contains them would no longer matter

Comment: checked the generated packages file and the file folder seems to be missing, but it is present when I run  `python setup.py sdist`

Comment: `MANIFEST.in` works only for `sdist`. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+include+package+data